# How do I resolve this "Access is denied" error which occurs when using xp_cmdshell in Microsoft SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xp-cmdshell

This is my entire routine:

```
Declare @AttFileType as char(5), @HQCo as int, @FormName as Varchar(15),       @KeyID as VarChar(10), @UniqueID as uniqueidentifier, @FilePath as Varchar(100), @StringCommand as Varchar(200)
Declare @AttID as int
DECLARE @cmd as VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @cmd2 as VARCHAR(500)


CREATE TABLE #tmp(eFileName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO #tmp
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'dir /B C:\Users\*****\Desktop\Test_Images';

Declare @FileName varchar(100)

Set @UniqueID = NewID()

While (Select Count(*) From #tmp where eFileName is not null) > 0
Begin

Select Top 1 @FileName = eFileName From #tmp

Set @FilePath = 'C:\Users\*****\Desktop\Test_Images\' + @FileName

Set @AttID = (Select TOP 1 AttachmentID FROM dbo.bHQAF ORDER BY AttachmentID DESC) + 1
Set @AttFileType = '.jpg'


Insert Into dbo.bHQAF (AttachmentID, AttachmentFileType)
Select @AttID, @AttFileType


SET @cmd = '
Declare @AttID2 as int, @AttFileType2 as char(5), @FilePath2 as Varchar(100)

Set @AttFileType2 = ''.jpg''
Set @AttID2 = (Select TOP 1 AttachmentID FROM dbo.bHQAF ORDER BY AttachmentID DESC)


Update dbo.bHQAF 
Set AttachmentData = (SELECT * From OPENROWSET (Bulk ''' + @FilePath + ''', Single_Blob) rs) 
Where AttachmentID = @AttID2 and AttachmentFileType = @AttFileType2'

Exec (@cmd)

Set @HQCo = 101
Set @FormName = 'HRCompAssets'
Set @KeyID = 'KeyID=2'


Insert Into dbo.bHQAT (HQCo, AttachmentID, FormName, KeyField, UniqueAttchID)
Select @HQCo, @AttID, @FormName, @KeyID, @UniqueID

Insert Into dbo.bHQAI (AttachmentID, HRCo)
Select @AttID, @HQCo

Update dbo.bHQAT 
Set Description = 'TEST3', AddDate =  GETDATE(),  AddedBy = '****', DocAttchYN = 'N',  DocName = 'Database', OrigFileName = @FileName, TableName = 'HRCA'
Where AttachmentID = @AttID and HQCo = @HQCo

Insert Into dbo.bHQAI (AttachmentID, HRCo)
Select @AttID, 101

Update dbo.bHRCA
Set UniqueAttchID = @UniqueID
Where HRCo = 101 and Asset = '00001'

Delete from #tmp Where eFileName = @FileName

End
```

I have verified that the code works, for loading a single image into the server, without this bit here:

```
-- Declarations here 

CREATE TABLE #tmp(eFileName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO #tmp
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'dir /B C:\Users\*****\Desktop\Test_Images';

While (Select Count(*) From #tmp where eFileName is not null) > 0
Begin

Select Top 1 @FileName = eFileName From #tmp


-- Rest of code here


Delete from #tmp Where eFileName = @FileName

End
```

But once the while loop and xp_cmdshell statements are added, the file name is returned as "Access is denied".

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

I'm not an expert in SQL, but I've been asked to load about 1000 PDF and JPEG files into the database and a script seemed to be the most logical approach.

When all is said and done, I would like the script to grab each image from the folder and load it into the database.

I'm open to using a different looping method if necessary.

Edit: 
I have also tried adding the following to the beginning of the code which didn't resolve the issue:

```
--Allow for SQL to use cmd shell
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1    -- To allow advanced options to be changed.
RECONFIGURE -- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1  -- To enable the feature.
RECONFIGURE -- To update the currently configured value for this feature.
```

I also went into Facets > Surface Area Configuration and made sure xp_cmdshell is enabled / allowed (true). It was also already marked true under Facets > Server Security.

Comment: could there be records in  #tmp where eFileName is an empty string ? I would change that in "While (Select Count(*) From #tmp where isnull(eFileName, '') <> '') > 0"

Comment: @GuidoG I tried replacing the while statement as you mentioned. Unfortunately, I'm still getting the error.

Comment: What is returned if you run just EXEC xp_cmdshell 'dir /B C:\Users\*****\Desktop\Test_Images'; ? Bear in mind this path is relative to the SQL server, not the client you run it from.

Comment: @GarethLyons running just EXEC xp_cmdshell 'dir /B C:\Users*****\Desktop\Test_Images returns ["access is denied" and Null.](http://i.imgur.com/3ktwHMS.jpg)

Comment: @JoshuaBryant sounding a lot like permissions to the path then, destination-data's answer has further info on that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of possible issues here.

xp_cmdShell runs on the server.  If that machine does not have a folder called `C:\Users\*****\Desktop\Test_Images` it will not work.

xp_CmdShell runs using the [service account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281953.aspx).  If that account does not have permissions on the target folder it will fail.

xp_CmdShell has to be enabled.  From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190693.aspx).

> The xp_cmdshell option is a SQL Server server configuration option
>   that enables system administrators to control whether the xp_cmdshell
>   extended stored procedure can be executed on a system. By default, the
>   xp_cmdshell option is disabled on new installations and can be enabled
>   by using the Policy-Based Management or by running the sp_configure
>   system stored procedure.

Comment: The folder exists and the account has full access to it. I am accessing the server through a remote desktop connection, does that make any difference?

Also, is the following what you would use to enable it?  

'EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1   
 -- To allow advanced options to be changed.
RECONFIGURE 
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1 
 -- To enable the feature.
RECONFIGURE 
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.'

Comment: Where does the folder exist?  On you desktop or the remote desktop?

Comment: Start with just `EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  `.  May already be enabled.  If not enabled read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx#Permissions) before turning on.  xp_CmdShell is a potential security risk.  If you do enable I would recommend disabling after use.

Comment: I ran ' EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1; ' and got [this](http://i.imgur.com/KXJQxij.jpg). Does that mean that it is already enabled? Also, the folder is in the servers Desktop folder (remote desktop).

Comment: That just means you've enabled viewing advanced options. You can check what's enabled by running select * from sys.configurations or just exec sp_configure - you want runvalue/value in use = 1 for xp_cmdshell. Also seconding destination-data's suggestion to turn it off again once you're done if it's not required elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks @GarethLyons I ran sp_configure and it returned the [this](http://i.imgur.com/D4CcIT6.jpg) which I assume means that this is enabled.

Comment: @JoshuaBryant yep, it is enabled from that. In any case, you'd be getting a very different error if it wasn't enabled.

Comment: Thank you @GarethLyons & destination-data for all of the help!

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out!

Thank you @destination-data & @GarethLyons for all the help!

You guys were right, there was an issue with the folder permissions I didn't realize that I would have to go into the folder and manually update the permissions to include "Service". Once I did, everything worked perfectly!

Thank you both again, sorry for the confusion.

For anyone else who is having this issue in the future, do the following first:

1) Go to the folder

2) Right click

3) Select properties

4) Select the Security tab

5) Click Advanced

6) Click Add

7) Click select a principle

8) Enter "Service" and Check Names

9) Select Service and click OK

10) Select the appropriate permissions under "Basic Permissions"

11) Select "Only apply these permissions to the object in this container"

12) Apply the changes and try running xp_cmdshell again

Comment: By far, the most helpful for the damn confusion of the problem of "access is denied". The key is to give "Service" the read access to the python script that I'm executing.